# PSR1 recommends that a file should either new symbols

Tags: php

I am using scrutinize-ci.com to check my code quality. But in some file it shows a message:

> For compatibility and reusability of your code, PSR1 recommends that a
>   file should either new symbols (like classes, functions, etc.) or have
>   side-effects (like outputting something, or including other files),
>   but not both at the same time. The first symbol is defined on line 23
>   and the first side effect is on line 12.

Here is the code for which issue is showing:

```
<?php
/**
 * class for handling form submission
 *
 * @package     ---
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php GNU Public License
 * @since       0.1
*/

// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'APPPATH' ) ) exit;

/*
 * hooks fired when app get initialized
 */


/**
 * Create global
 */
function app_form_global( ) {

    $valid_fields = new APP_Fields;

    .....
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please show us the code so we can better explain it?

Comment: Ahh, you preform the action in calling `exit`. Do you perform any other actions in the file outside of the functions you define? If not, the define doesn't need to be checked at the beginning of the file - just before calling the functions.

Comment: oh, yes I got it. Thanks it solved my issue. You can post your comment as answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer per request. ^^

You are performing the action in calling exit. Do you perform any other actions in the file outside of the functions you define? If not, the define doesn't need to be checked at the beginning of the file - just before calling the functions